# How do I organize posts based on their taxonomy?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have a huge assortment of posts. They each belong to a taxonomy (let's say Taxonomy 1, Taxonomy 2, Taxonomy 3, and Taxonomy 4).

On the page where they are displayed - I wanted them to be displayed according to the taxonomy. (Taxonomy 1 posts first, Taxonomy 2 posts second, etc)

How can I programmatically make this happen on the page? Currently they are just displayed with the standard foreach loop

Comment: To clarify, do you mean they each belong to a different taxonomy, or they each belong to a differ _term_ in the same taxonomy?

Comment: I think it would be a different term within the same taxonomy. Let's say the taxonomy is called "Groups" and they have terms "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", etc